# Does Google Cloud Storage scan the entire bucket if I want read a few files?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm looking to migrate from Hive to Google Cloud Storage. The upstream job is dumping files in HDFS. In Hive, I maintain partitions on HDFS and while querying only the specific partition(s) are scanned.

On GCS, I understand that there is no concept of folders. So if I'm dumping files inside a bucket where the path structure matches what I had in HDFS, like this:

```
gs://my-bucket/year=2021/month=12/day=6/a.txt
gs://my-bucket/year=2021/month=12/day=7/b.txt
gs://my-bucket/year=2021/month=12/day=8/c.txt
```

This data will constantly grow over time. Now, if I want to query this bucket to fetch only the file written today, does GCS internally scan the entire bucket (because there are no folders and each file is an object)?

My use case writes terabytes of data each day and the most common consumption pattern is to access 'yesterday' data.

How can I model my storage on GCS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deep dive into Cloud Storage is interesting. You have 2 parts in the storage management:

- The data storage it self
- The metadata management

The storage itself isn't interesting here. It's based on Colossus storage system, something internal to google to store anything.

The metadata management is more interesting. In fact, you have a database that reference all the files and where the parts are stored in Colossus.

The metadata are stored on BigTable, and the key, is your filename (that can explain many thing, especially the hotspot if your file name are too similar, you always use the same BigTable node and create a hotspot).

Anyway, because the key is your file name, you can only search by the prefix of the key (that BigTable allows). Therefore, if you want the files for a specific day, you search by the prefix `year=2021/month=12/day=8/`.

So, the bucket isn't fully scanned, only the metadata database is scanned and you can get only the files that you want like that.

Comment: This is interesting. So what I gather by extension to your answer is that if I rename an object, only the metadata in BigTable would get updated, and there won't be any actual data movement in the storage layer. Is that correct as well?

And if I run a command such as `gsutil du -s gs://my-bucket/year=2021/month=12` to get the size of all files for the month of Dec, only files matching this prefix will be scanned and the rest of the bucket will remain untouched, right?

Comment: If you change the key (i.e. the path name of your file in the bucket) you have to create a new entry and therefore you have to copy the content in addition of the metadata to the new key entry. Cloud Storage is designed like that, and I don't know the constraint behind the scene. For the `gsutil du` you have right.

Comment: @Rajat - 1) Cloud Storage is **immutable**. That means changes require copying the data to a new location with the changes. For example, a rename is a copy and delete. 2) How you name your objects can affect performance. Your naming convention is not optimum. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#naming-convention

Comment: @JohnHanley - thanks yes, I saw the docs around using prefixes to avoid hotspots. It's slightly inconvenient because the file path is important to me for this specific use case, but I can understand why that's the case at scale.

Answer (score 0):

As @John Hanley mentioned, the [naming convention](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate#naming-convention) is not optimal here.

To maintain a high request rate, avoid using sequential names. Using random object names gives better load distribution.

Comment: On GCS is there a recommended approach to handle this kind of "partitioning" strategy which would normally apply on HDFS?